# Setting textboxes numbering to decimals

Tags: vb.net

i have a textbox and it will basically just be filled with figures, how can i set it to show after it was typed in the form of `### ###` [WITH THE SPACE BETWEEN THOUSANDS,ETC]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if you're looking for the [`MaskedTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx).

Set it's [`Mask` property][1] to `### ###`.

---

**#**

Digit or space, optional. If this position is blank in the mask, it will be rendered as a space in the Text property. Plus (+) and minus (-) signs are allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Below coding it will solve your problem

If you give a value as **9786952**

Then it display that value as **9 786 952**

I have wrote this in Button_click Event

```
    Me.TextBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:n0}", CDbl(Me.TextBox1.Text))
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text.Replace(",", " ")
```

-Pandian

Answer (score 0):

If you are using data binding you can define a format.

- Create a model for your data, i.e. a class with properties for the data of each textbox, checkbox etc., with the correct data type. Your number property must be typed as a number (`int` or `decimal` etc.).
- Create an object data source in the "Data Sources" task pane.
- Drag and drop your number field from the data source to the form.  This creates a textbox.
  A `BindingSource` and a `BindingNavigator` component are added automatically to the form. If you don't need navigation, you can delete the `BindingNavigator` component, but keep the `BindingSource`.
- Select the number textbox you just added. In the properties window open "(DataBindings)" and click on the three dots (...) next to "(Advanced)". Here you can select a format type from a list. If you select "Custom", a field "Custom format" appears where you can enter "000 000" or "### ###" as format.
- Assign an instance of your model to the `BindingSource`.

```
MyModel _model = new MyModel { Number = 123456 };

MyBindingSource.DataSource = _model;
```

The binding mechanism automatically converts any number from the model to a formatted text in the textbox and converts text entered in the textbox back to a number in the model. Very practical.